# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'range' referenced before assignment

Tags: variables, range

I'm new to Python.
I jsut found an eroor in my code and I have no idea what's the problem, I already searched on multiple websites with the error message, but I haven't gotten any solution.
I didin't even put range into a variable so it's kinda weird.

```
import turtle           # j'ai pas mis de couleur pour l'instant car jsp comment faire , à mon avis il faut choisir une rangée de couleur et ensuite utiliser la commande rand

import random

couleur=[(255,127,36),
         (238,118,33),
         (205,102,29),
         (255,114,86),
         (238,106,80),
         (205,91,69),
         (255,127,0),
         (238,118,0),
         (205,102,0),
         (139,69,0),
         (139,69,19)]

def random_color():
    return random.choice(couleur)

def briques():                 # cette fonction permet de tracer la ligné de brique
    for i in range (12):      # j'aurais pu mettre nblong , mais sa aurait était bizarre, c'est le nb de ligne de brique
        for i in range (12):  # c'est pour la ligne de 1ere brique
            
            random_color()
            
            color(couleur)
            fillcolor(couleur)
            begin_fill()
```

By the way this is a project on turtle, we have to build a house (in 2d) with turtles features.

Comment: This is not a complete program.  at least you need a `pass` statement in your `for` loop.  I suspect there's something else missing.  You have no imports here, and range is normally a b uiltin function

Comment: Yeah, it's probably because I don't have a pass , my loop is very long and confusing.
I'm going to make a function instead of redoing the same thign over and over. I'll tell you if it chanegs anything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try defining i with no value
for (I) in Range
define I
ex.
i=" " or i=0